# using button feature in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app currently that uses a callback for 5 user inputs to print some features. The code is below.

What I'd like to do is make it so that instead of a user adjusting a feature and the function automatically printing the whole set with just the one adjusted feature, I'd like the user to be able to adjust any or all of the features without the function printing, and then be able to hit a submit button to print all the newly adjusted features.

As you can see I've taken a shot at it, but its not working.

```
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Regression Analyzer for Individual Market Securities', style={'textAlign': 'center'
        }),
   
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id = 'my-date',
        min_date_allowed=date(2015, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date(2020, 11, 11),
        initial_visible_month=date(2017, 8, 5),
        start_date=date(2015, 1, 1),
        end_date=date(2020, 11, 1)),
        
    dcc.Dropdown(id = 'MA',
    options=[
        {'label': 'Day Average', 'value': 'Day Average'},
        {'label': '7 Day Avg', 'value': '7 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '50 Day Avg', 'value': '50 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '200 Day Avg', 'value': '200 Day Avg'}
    ], value='Day Average'),
        
    dcc.Input(id = 'Name',
    placeholder='Enter stock ticker ...',
    type='text',
    value='AAPL'),
    
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
    
    dcc.Loading(
    dcc.Graph(id='figure-scatter'),
    type='cube',
    color='#f15d27'),
    
    dcc.Loading(
    dcc.Graph(id='figure-regression'),
    type='cube',
    color='#f15d27'),
    
    dcc.Loading(
    dcc.Graph(id='figure-table'),
    type='cube',
    color='#f15d27'),
    
    html.Div(id='my-output')
    
    ])

@app.callback(Output(component_id='figure-scatter', component_property='figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')]
    [dash.dependencies.State("Name", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.State("MA", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.State("my-date", "start_date"),
     dash.dependencies.State("my-date", "end_date")] )
def compare_to_market1(Name, MA, start_date, end_date):
    print(Name, MA, start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: "its not working" is not diagnostically useful. If there's an error, please include the full message in the question. If there's no message, be clear about what the expected behavior is, compared to the actual behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback has 1 input and 4 states, so the function should have 5 args, but it only has 4 as you've written it. It should look like this:

```py
@app.callback(Output(component_id='figure-scatter', component_property='figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')]
    [dash.dependencies.State("Name", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.State("MA", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.State("my-date", "start_date"),
     dash.dependencies.State("my-date", "end_date")] )
def compare_to_market1(submit_click, Name, MA, start_date, end_date):
    print(Name, MA, start_date, end_date)
```